# Splitting a String into Tokens and Storing the Delimiters in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, string-matching

I have a string like this:

```
a  b   c       d
```

I process my string like this:

```
   chomp $line;
    my @tokens = split /\s+/, $line;
    my @new_tokens;
    foreach my $token (@tokens) {    
        push @new_tokens, some_complex_function( $token );
    }
    my $new_str = join ' ', @tokens;
```

I'd like to re-join the string with the original whitespace. Is there some way that I can store the whitespace from split and re-use it later? Or is this going to be a huge pain? It's mostly cosmetic, but I'd like to preserve the original spaces from the input string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you split with a regex with capturing parentheses, the split pattern will be included in the resulting list (see [perldoc -f split](http://perldoc.per.org/functions/split.html)):

```
my @list = split /(\s+)/, 'a  b   c       d';
print Data::Dumper::Dumper(\@list);

VAR1 = [
          'a',
          '  ',
          'b',
          '   ',
          'c',
          '       ',
          'd'
        ];
```

Answer (score 4):

Just split on word boundaries:

```
split /\b/, $line;
```

For your example, this will give:

```
('a','  ','b','   ','c','       ','d')
```

**EDIT:** As brian d foy pointed out, `\b` uses the wrong character classes, Following my original idea, I came up with using look-around assertions. This looks way more complicated than Ether's answer, though:

```
split /(?:(?<=\S)(?=\s)|(?<=\s)(?=\S))/, $line;
```

Comment: This may accidently split on things that aren't whitespace boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I wrote the original answer without thinking about `\w` vs. `\s`. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply do: `my $new_str = uc( $line );` ?

UPDATE - original uc() is just a shorthand for "more complex function".

Well, generally you can also:

```
$line =~ s/(\S+)/more_complex_function($1)/ge;
```

Comment: Because my real case is more complicated, and this is just an example.